# Can't add language translation support to Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, translate, po

I am trying to add language/translation support for my Wordpress plugin using *POEdit* software to create *.po* files, but the code isn't working and there are no screen error printing out.

My plugin is located in **/plugins/site-status/** and the languages directory is located as **/plugins/site-status/languages/**. In **/languages/** directory all .po files have names such as **site-status-en_US.po** (the unique identifier is called ***site-status***)
Here is the language support code:

```
function    status_language_init() {
          load_plugin_textdomain( 'site-status', false, 'site-status/languages/' ); 
        }
        add_action('init', 'status_language_init');
```

Here is the test code for outputing the default/translated text:

```
echo _x( 'test', 'site-status' );
```

I very much look forward for your help!

*Thanks in advance and with best wishes,
WHOAMi*

Comment: See [wordpress.stackexchange.com → translation](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation).

Comment: I have already surfed around stack and google search. Nothing comes handy to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug this, check the return value of [`load_plugin_textdomain()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain). And don’t rely on a directory name of your plugin. The user can change it.

```php
$path        = basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages';
$lang_loaded = load_plugin_textdomain( 'site-status', FALSE, $path );
// die harder!
! $lang_loaded and die( $path . ' not found' );
```

Comment: site-status/languages not found

Comment: P.S. Id voted for your answer but i joined here just few minutes ago. Thanks anyway! :/